# alcohol into Doha airport to Canada?

Tags: transit, canada, alcohol, qatar-airways, doh

I am going to be returning to Canada soon from Lebanon and I will have a layover in Hamad airport in Doha. I have several bottles of alcohol in my luggage and possibly another one from Beirut international.

Will there be any issues or questions with this? I will not be drinking any in the airport and I will not be entering Qatar.

Comment: Can you confirm you mean your checked luggage? You are unlikely to be able to bring onboard any liquids (beyond the usual 100 ml per container 1l total) with the exception of those bought at the airport (airside), and for those you need to make sure they are kept in their original sealed bag. Also note that there are (very low) limits on how much alcohol you can import into Canada without having to declare them and pay tax on them.

Comment: Not my hand luggage. My luggage that I will only get when in Montreal. I do intend on declaring when I arrive in Canada.